# How to ensure the last commit(s) will not get lost after git checkout?

Tags: git

Before git checkout I'd like to ensure that my last commit(s) is not orphan and not get lost.

The commit(s) may get lost in case of detached HEAD for example. The fact of loosing the commits is nicely reported after finishing "git checkout":

```
Warning: you are leaving 2 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  8fdb039 Message log for lost commit 2
  d8edb79 Message log for lost commit 1
...
Switched to branch 'master'
```

But, I'd like to check BEFORE running 'git checkout'. --dry-run option for git checkout would be a kind of solution (git 1.7.9.5 doesn't have such option).

Need an option to abort git checkout in case some commit(s) going to be lost. Or an option to quick check if the last commit(s) is orphan.

Comment: I think not http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout, you could run `git status` or `git branch` before checkout to check if you're on a branch or not, but I fear that might not be what you want

Comment: Thanks Tim, yes, this is not exactly what I want. Need an option to abort git checkout in case some commit(s) going to be lost. Or an option to quick check if the last commit(s) is orphan.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want something like `git branch --contains HEAD`, which will tell you if your current `HEAD` commit is included in any of the currently existing branches...

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks @twalberg ! So, this is the solution:
`test "'git branch --contains HEAD'" = '* (no branch)' && echo LOSE || echo OK`
But, **it will not work** after git maintainers decide to change the output string. Still, it would be great to have some "hard-coded" git option and proper error code.

Answer (score 4):

When you are in a detached HEAD, `git branch` will give `* (no branch)`, and `git status` will give `# Not currently on any branch.`

Note that git has been conceived to make branching easy, so you should avoid working in a detach HEAD state and only use this state for "inspection and discardable experiments". When you start modifying anything, simply creates a new branch with `git branch non_existing branch` to create a branch before checking out.

If you left without creating a branch, your commit is not necessarily lost. You can retrieve the ID of the commit with `git log -2 HEAD`and then return to it with `git checkout ID` to create a branch

Comment: Thanks, Math, I know. But, I'm talking about automation. For example following cmd allows to automatically check if HEAD is detached: "git symbolic-ref HEAD && echo OK || echo DETACHED". But, there is no way to automatically check for orphaned commit(s) BEFORE running 'git checkout'

Comment: You can create a new command to do it. Put `git symbolic-ref HEAD && git checkout $1 || echo DETACHED` in a script, then use this new command instead of `git checkout`.

Comment: No, this is not a solution, because such checkout will simply fail in case of detached HEAD. But, I need a checkout command which SUCCEED in case of detached HEAD, but FAIL in case HEAD commit is orphan.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

`git reflog -1 HEAD | grep commit || (git checkout $1 && exit 0) && (git branch --contain HEAD | grep \\w || git branch --contain HEAD | grep \\w) && git checkout $1 || echo "Detached HEAD with orphan commit"` in a script will do it.
If the last action is not a commit, checkout is performed, otherwise, checkout is performed only if there is a branch or a tag pointing to this commit.

Comment: erratum : use `git branch --contain HEAD | grep "[^)]$"` instead of `git branch --contain HEAD`, it will consider that being pointed by HEAD is equivalent to being pointed by a branch.

Answer (score 0):

No need to be so cautious, when you see the "leaving commits behind" message just tag the history you left behind.

```
git tag some-useful-name @{-1}
```

There's [lots of ways](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) to refer to commits, and [everything you've done in the last month stays in your repository](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html#_configuration).  Git doesn't, ever, lose commits.

Comment: In other words: tag your HEAD before every checkout?

Comment: @IvanGetta You could even automate the tag naming! You could generate something unique to identify every commit. Something like a hash value of its content. ;)

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Yeah, just to have peaceful sleep, before every checkout not forget to run:`git tag $(git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1) HEAD`

Comment: No, in response to the "leaving commits behind" message.  It was probably a whole lot easier to understand than for people who already understood it before, sorry I didn't pick up on the potential confusion.